# Is there a way to stop/cancel/kill Hadoop map tasks from within the Mapper code?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I need to cancel map tasks when I detect invalid filenames.

In the `setup()` method of my Mapper I have code that validates the `inputSplit`'s filename. In case the filename does not match the expected pattern (can happen if the submitted job was given wrong `inputPaths`), I want to skip this map task.

I don't want to throw an exception and have Hadoop retry the task. I also don't want to set `mapreduce.reduce.maxattempts` to lower than the default.